# How to rank the table columns based on duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, rank

I've a table like this And I want to rank it based on combination of cksid and guid.

```
cksid       guid
----------- -----------
1           301
1           301
1           301
2           303
2           303
3           303
4           303
4           303
4           303
```

Output should be like

```
cksid       guid           rank
----------- ----------- ----------
1           301             1
1           301             2
1           301             3
2           303             1
2           303             2
3           303             1
4           303             1
4           303             2
4           303             3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

You just have to use the row_number function

```
 select cksid ,guid ,
    row_number() over (partition by cksid ,guid order by (select 0)) as rank
    from <Table>
```

row_number() requires an order by clause. Here you dont have a third column to order by. So I am just putting (Select 0) which will order the output in any order, which doesn't matter to us. We could have given order by cksid ,guid also , but I think which is a little over head as we can get the same result by just giving (select 0)

Comment: +1 : Although, when using the `(SELECT 0)` 'trick', I would advise adding an explanation as to why...

Comment: @Dems: Thank u for your comment. I have added the explanation. Please feel free to add if its not good enough

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cksid, guid,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cksid,guid ORDER BY cksid,guid)
FROM   youtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test11(cksid int,guid int)
INSERT INTO test11
VALUES(1,301),
(1,301),
(1,301),
(2,303),
(2,303),
(3,303),
(4,303),
(4,303),
(4,303)

select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cksid,guid order by guid) as ranks from test11
```